# How to delete object by id with EF Core, if entity tracked and I don't have a reference to that object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using C# and EF Core 6. I can't remove object, if it was added by another method and I haven't access to the attached object, but I know its `Id`.

Code methods:

```
class objEntity
{
    public int Id;
}
...        
DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

public void CreateObj(objEntity obj)
{
    var addedObjEntity = dbContext.ObjEntities.Add(obj);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // if I detach addedObjEntity from dbContext here, all work fine,
    // is it possible to remove obj from DB, if I use same dbContext, 
    // but don't have access to the addedObjEntity and I know its Id.

    // dbContext.Entry(addedObjEntity).State = EntityState.Detached; - if use this - all work
    // if above line is commented, here state of the addedObjEntity = Unchanged
 }
        
 public void DeleteEntity(long objId)
 {
     var objEntity = new ObjEntity() { Id = objId };
     dbContext.ObjEntities.Remove(objEntity); // <-- here would be an exception
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
 ....
    
 // now we will call the methods 
 int Id = 10;
 CreateObj(new objEntity(){Id = 10});
 DeleteEntity(Id);
```

Exception message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ObjEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: The code is wrong, for 2 reasons. 1) A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. *Don't* call `SaveChanges` unless you want to commit *all* changes at the very end of a use case. 2) You can get an object by ID with `DbSet.Find`. If the object is tracked you'll get back the tracked object, otherwise a new one will be loaded. No matter what, you can use `Remove` and the deletion will be persisted along with all other pending changes when you call SaveChanges at the end

Comment: Methods named `DeleteEntity`, `CreateObj` are a *very* strong smell indicating that a low-level CRUD class was placed over the high-level Unit-of-Work. This breaks EF's consistency model and is behind 80% of the EF questions at SO

Comment: You can delete a object without going through the Unit-of-Work tracking or loading an existing copy with `context.Products.Where(prod=>prod.Id=45).ExecuteDelete()` too. Essentially, this creates and executes a `DELETE Products Where ID=45`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
 EF Core 6 (which I use) don't support ExecuteDelete(), but DbSet.Find work like a charm! Thank You.